# Java Flow of execution - overridden method gets executed first than the constructor

Tags: java, debugging

I have the following code, in the same java file.

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.io.File;

public class MainClass2{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
                 javax.swing.JFileChooser jfc = new MyFileChooser();
                     File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
             }

      });
   }
}

class MyFileChooser extends javax.swing.JFileChooser{
    public MyFileChooser(){
        System.out.println("constructor call");
    }
    @Override
    public java.io.File getSelectedFile(){
        System.out.println("call to getSelectedFile");
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run it, the output gives me

`call to getSelectedFile`

`constructor call`

`call to getSelectedFile`

Shouldn't the output be

`constructor call`

`call to getSelectedFile`

I'm using java 5.

Comment: Where is your call to getSelectedFile?

Comment: My bad, actually in my original code, im calling it the usual way, after instantiation of MyFileChooser. But as u can see, even if I don't do an explicit call to `getSelectedFile`. I'll update my code.

Comment: you never need to call `getSelectedFile` , this is calling inside 'JFileChooser' when you choose the file

Comment: Note that there is an implicit call to `super()` at the start of the constructor, that might call other methods. You can also add `Thread.dumpStack()` to `getSelectFile()` to show how it gets there.

Comment: @Alya'a Gamal what do you mean I never need to call `getSelectedFile`? Then how can I get the file chosen from the dialog?

Comment: JFileChooser call this function when you select the file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MyFileChooser`'s constructor is equivalent to:

```
public MyFileChooser() {
    super(); // ***
    System.out.println("constructor call");
}
```

The first call to `getSelectedFile()` is made by `MyFileChooser`'s base class constructor, which is invoked implicitly at the point marked `***` above, before the `System.out.println("constructor call")`.

Here is the stack trace:

```
MyFileChooser.getSelectedFile() line: 16    
AquaFileChooserUI.installComponents(JFileChooser) line: 1436    
AquaFileChooserUI.installUI(JComponent) line: 122   
MyFileChooser(JComponent).setUI(ComponentUI) line: 670  
MyFileChooser(JFileChooser).updateUI() line: 1798   
MyFileChooser(JFileChooser).setup(FileSystemView) line: 360 
MyFileChooser(JFileChooser).<init>(File, FileSystemView) line: 333  
MyFileChooser(JFileChooser).<init>() line: 286  
MyFileChooser.<init>() line: 11
```

Comment: To prevent problems like this, all methods called by a constructor should be made final so that they cannot be overridden by a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor:

```
public MyFileChooser(){
    System.out.println("constructor call");
}
```

seems have nothing to do with the base class' constructor. However there is an implicit super call to javax.swing.JFileChooser(), which makes call to `getSelectedFile();`. So your constructor is actually like this:

```
public MyFileChooser(){
    super();
    System.out.println("constructor call");
}
```

Because jfc is object of MyFileChooser, this method:

```
@Override
public java.io.File getSelectedFile(){
    System.out.println("call to getSelectedFile");
    return null;
}
```

is get called. "call to getSelectedFile" is printed out, followed by "call to getSelectedFile".

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the stack trace, you'll see that the `JFileChooser` constructor calls `setup(FileSystemView view)` which calls `updateUI()`, which calls `setUI()` in the JComponent superclass, which calls `installUI` on a platform-specific UI class, this class then calls `installComponents`, which calls `getSelectedFile` again.

A quote from Effective Java 2nd Edition:

> There are a few more restrictions that a class must obey to allow inheritance. Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, directly or indirectly. If you violate this rule, program failure will result. The superclass constructor runs before the subclass constructor, so the overriding method in the subclass will be invoked before the subclass constructor has run. If the overriding method depends on any initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will not behave as expected.

But of course, the Swing toolkit doesn't always follow this advice ;-)

Full stack trace:

```
at MyFileChooser.getSelectedFile(MainClass2.java:27)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaFileChooserUI.installComponents(AquaFileChooserUI.java:1436)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaFileChooserUI.installUI(AquaFileChooserUI.java:122)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:670)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.updateUI(JFileChooser.java:1798)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.setup(JFileChooser.java:360)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.<init>(JFileChooser.java:333)
```