# Can I call a set Method inside a Constructor

Tags: java, constructor, encapsulation

I have a number of set methods setup and using a constructor to initiate their value as follows. It is working but I am concerned as to whether it is a normal Java convention to do so (is it normal to call a set method inside a constructor?).

The alternative way I can think of is to call an empty constructor and call the set methods one by one in the main method to set the value. I find this second method tedious. Please advice if what I have done is fine/ within Java convention or if there is a better way to do it. Do tell if I need to post more code to make my question more clearer. I can post it all if it would make better sense. Thank you.

```
public Person(String foreName,String surName, int age, double height, String gender){
        personCount++; 
        setForeName(foreName);
        setSurName(surName);
        setAge(age);
        setHeight(height);
        setGender(gender); 
    }
```

Comment: Constructor can directly assign values to class variables (without using setters).  `this.foreName=forename`

Comment: Yes; constructors can call functions.

Comment: Beware that if a derived class overrides those functions, trouble can ensue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not just a matter of taste. If there isn't any extra logic in the `setXXX()` methods, the convention is to assign the attributes directly in the constructor:

```
this.foreName = foreName;
this.surName = surName;
```

... And so on. But if there *is* extra logic in the `setXXX()` methods, then you should use them as required. Say, a call to logging logic or similar:

```
public void setForeName(String pForeName) {
    log.info("setting new foreName value: " + pForeName);
    this.foreName = pForeName;
}
```

See how the last line in `setForeName()` is the same as performing a direct assignment? Also notice that calling a `setXXX()` might have a very, very small cost in performance (most likely optimized away by the JIT compiler). Under normal circumstances you should optimize for readability and clarity above all, and IMHO using a direct assignment here is the preferred option.

Answer (score 8):

If using `this` doesn't bypass the validation rules defined in the setters, it's just a matter of taste:

```
public Person(String foreName,String surName, int age, double height, String gender){
    personCount++; 
    this.foreName = foreName;
    //same goes for the rest of the params
}
```

Comment: This bypasses all validation rules that might have been set in setters  so you have to be very wary of this. It's safer to just use the setters everytime (when a validation rule might be added in the future this would cause you to have 2 styles in your constructor). Or you can change it all around when a setter is implemented, depends on preference in that aspect.

Comment: I am using the set methods cos I am using some conditions in them. For example I don't want age to have a negative value. I didn't want to start placing if statements inside the constructor. Thus I let the set method handle the conditions

Comment: Also when you skip set methods and directly go from private variable straight to assigning value to it via constructor such as: this.var = var - Is this considered as a setter too?

Comment: No, it's considered as "assigning value to a class member".

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that setters are exposed to the public, which means it can be overriden by its subclasses. When you create a subclass with the intent of modifying the behavior of one of its setters, the first thing that it will do in the construtor of the subclass is to call its superclass' constructor, which means that these setters and the added logic inside it will be executed when in fact you actually want modify the behavior of one of its setters. [This kind of problems are often times hard to spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805028/java-flow-of-execution-overriden-method-gets-executed-first-than-the-construct).

A quote from Effective Java Item 17

> Constructors must not invoke overridable methods, directly or
>   indirectly. If    you violate this rule, program failure will result.
>   The superclass constructor runs   before the subclass constructor, so
>   the overriding method in the subclass will get    invoked before the
>   subclass constructor has run. If the overriding method depends    on any
>   initialization performed by the subclass constructor, the method will
>   not   behave as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to use set methods in the constructor. I don't know if it's really a convention to do it with `this.var = var`, but it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem in calling a setter in a constructor.  In fact, if you plan to have setters carry additional logic, using the method gives you better encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

why are you call set method inside constructor ?
try this

```
private String foreName;
private String surName;
private int age;
private double height;
private String gender


public Person(String foreName,String surName, int age, double height, String gender){
        personCount++; 
        this.foreName = foreName;
        this.surName = surName;
        this.age = age;
        this.height = height;
        this.gender = gender; 
    }

/// setter and getter methods of above private variables..
```

Answer (score -2):

What I've been taught to do thus far is to provide the setters and getters within the constructor, then actually set and get it within whatever method, (in your case main), that you want to use it for. But, that's if your fields are private. If they're public like in your case, then I would say setting your variables in the field or constructor, then calling them where/whenever you want to use them makes much more sense...